# jqGrid - multiselect rows and rowselect

Tags: asp.net, jqgrid, jqgrid-asp.net

I have a jqGrid with multi select set to true using the asp.net jqGrid. 
I want it to select multipole rows then click a button and something will apply to the IDs for all those rows.  At the same time, clicking on a row should populate some fields (ex. textboxes).  The problem is I've used the rowselect method and although that allows me to populate the form on row select it does not allow me to select multiple checkbox rows.

Is there a way to make the checkboxes not activate the rowselect method? 
OR is the alternative to create a hyperlink on the result of the value in a cell that calls a method in code behind passing the ID? Is my last idea even possible?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In order for checkboxes not to activate the rowselect event , you can use cellselect instead of rowselect function. Under cellselect  function , check for column index if its not the  checkbox column , then execute the code which you have written for rowselect.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. Is the cellselect function in the .net jqgrid feature?  I'm not entirely sure how to add it. 
The code I have to set up the rowselect is on the .net side.
<jqg:JQGrid id="jqContacts" Width=800px MultiSelect=true Height=100  OnDataRequesting="jqContacts_DataRequesting" OnRowSelecting="jqContacts_RowSelect" runat="server">

Answer (score 0):

You may need to write client side code [javascript] , you can add 
 tag [server] and add cellselect option to it . For more information check the link below

http://www.trirand.net/forum/default.aspx?g=posts&t=1452

Comment: I'm fairly new at this so correct me if I'm wrong.  if i set up client side code to get the selected id of a cell ... this is done in Javascript.  THen I need to call a c# code behind method to do some processing and then populate the form values.  The problem i believe here is i can only call a static method from javascript. 

I wonder if there is a way to see in the row selected method if there is a way to see if the cell clicked is a checkbox? 

Thanks for your help